# Using a for loop Calculate the sum of the values in this dictionary and do not use sum() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, sum

Using a for loop Calculate the sum of the values in this dictionary and do not use sum() function?

```
Dictionary = {"001": {"a" : [1, 5, 6], "b" : [2, 8, 9] }, "002": {"c" : [6.89, 5.67, 1.24], "d" : [9.32, 6, 78] }}
```

Ive tried to answer this in many methods but i always get this error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'
```

Thank you !

Comment: Show us some code attempts

Comment: would you like the sum of all numbers? or would you like a list that has the sums of each index in each of the number lists? (they are all of length 3 which leads me to ask this)

Comment: Could you elaborate please

Answer (score -1):

Use a nested loop according to the data structure:

```
total = 0

for dct in Dictionary.values():  # the outermost dict's values are dicts again ...
    for lst in dct.values():     # ... whose values are lists ...
        for num in lst:          # ... whose elements are addable numbers
            total += num

total
# 138.12
```

Comment: dicti3 = {"001": {"a" : [1, 5, 6], "b" : [2, 8, 9] }, "002": {"c" : [6.89, 5.67, 1.24], "d" : [9.32, 6, 78] }}

total = 0

for dct in dicti3.values():
    for lst in dicti3.values():
        for num in lst:
            total += num
            
print(total)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-3bf2629ab373> in <module>
      6     for lst in dicti3.values():
      7         for num in lst:
----> 8             total += num
      9 
     10 print(total)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Thank you for your response but I still got an error as displayed above

Comment: You didn't copy it properly: `for lst in dicti3...` must be `for lst in dct...`.

Comment: Ah I see, there was an error in my code initially that's why i changed it. you're correct. It worked thank you.

Comment: so why is the total here different from the one provided below which is 24.67, is it because his method only uses numerical values ? thank you.

Comment: Nah, the other solution is just wrong. He keeps overriding `som1` in the loop. Effectively, you only get the sum of all the second elements.

Comment: Ohh i see that now ! thank you for the clarification

Answer (score -2):

I think you was trying to make a sum the dictionary with the operand +
Instead you need to get every single number inside of the list (remind that the list is inside of a dictionary and this dictionary is inside of another)
So i make a for loop:

```
Dictionary = {"001": {"a": [1, 5, 6], "b": [2, 8, 9]}, "002": {"c": [6.89, 5.67, 1.24], "d": [9.32, 6, 78]}}
for c in range(0, len(Dictionary['001'])):
    l1 = Dictionary['001']['a']
    l2 = Dictionary['001']['b']
    som1 = l1[c] + l2[c]
for c in range(0, len(Dictionary['002'])):
    l1 = Dictionary['002']['c']
    l2 = Dictionary['002']['d']
    som2 = l1[c] + l2[c]
somt = som1 + som2
print(somt)
```

Comment: so why is the total here different from the one provided below which is 138

Comment: This does not solve the problem at all. You keep overriding `som1` and `som2` in their respective loops. Also, you loop over ranges corresponding to the inner dict's length, which is `2`. Ergo, the end result is the sum of all the second list elements: `5+8+5.67+6`